# Is there a way to get the "customdata" property of a clicked point in Plotly?

Tags: javascript, plotly

As far as I understood the documentation of Plotly the clickEvent can only hand over the coordinates of the nearest point to the cursor position. But is there any way to get the clicked point's properties like "text" or in my case the "customdata"?

Edit:
I am not even sure, if I used the customdata property right:

```js
    var trace = {
      x: [5],
      y: [7],
      name: 'example',
      hovertemplate: '%{text}',
      text: ['example'],
      mode: 'markers',
      visible: 'legendonly',
      marker: {
      size: [257],
      sizeref: 2,
      sizemode: 'area',
      opacity: 0.3,
      customdata: ['https://google.com/']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`customdata` needs to be assigned to your trace data, not the `marker` object.

The `plotly_click` event returns the points with all its attributes. You can then access `customdata` and `text` for each clicked point.

The example below is based on https://plotly.com/javascript/click-events/#binding-to-click-events

```js
const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
  d3 = Plotly.d3,
  N = 26,
  x = d3.range(N),
  y = d3.range(N).map( d3.random.normal() ),
  customdata = d3.range(N).map(x => characters[x]),
  text = d3.range(N).map(x => characters[x] + '-' + characters[x])
  data = [ { 
    x: x, 
    y: y, 
    type: 'scatter',
    customdata: customdata,
    text: text,
    mode: 'markers', 
    marker: {size: 16} 
  } ],
  layout = {
    hovermode: 'closest',
    title: 'Click on Points',
    hovertemplate: '%{text}'
  };

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
    var msg = 'Closest point clicked:';
    for(var i=0; i < data.points.length; i++){
      msg += '\ncustomdata = ' + data.points[i].customdata;
      msg += '\ntext = ' + data.points[i].text;
    }
    alert(msg);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>  
  <div id="myDiv" style:width: 100%></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Although I have a list with links saved in the customdata, the customdata returns "undefined" :(

Comment: Maybe it's because I used the customdata property wrong. Could you check my code I added, please? :)

Comment: @Spyrex: see updated answer, I think the issue is that your customdata is part of the marker object and not the trace data.